# Как в загруженном растровом изображении распознать круг, квадрат или треугольник?

Tags: php, алгоритм, laravel, графика

Фигура черная на белом фоне.

Хотя бы скажите,где копать. Может, библиотека есть для этого?

Comment: Постройте выпуклые оболочки. Сосчитайте на них число "крутых" поворотов. Три -> треугольник, иначе квадрат.

Comment: Постройте минимальный описанный ориентированный прямоугольник. Сравните его площадь с количеством закрашенных пикселей внутри. Если почти всё закрашено - квадрат, если отношение близко к 0.5 - треугольник.

Comment: практически единственной являетя opencv. не знаю есть ли он для php. вам следует искать линии на градиентах по теням. вьезхать за день не получится.

Comment: второй вариант. может от вас хотят нейронную сеть? тогда вам в распознавание образов, задача котики и собаки.

Comment: Дело идет, напишу, если подлучится

Comment: Вроде получилось. Сейчас дам ответ

Answer (score 1):

Длинно для комментария, приведу ответом:

Попробуйте подход с использованием [моментов изображения](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment).

Если на картинке только одна фигура, считайте моменты по всем пикселам, если несколько - разделите на связные области, моменты считайте по областям.

Для образцов посмотрите, будут ли для данного множества фигур моменты давать явные признаки, позволяющие их различить. Если недостаточно, посмотрите ещё [моменты Ху](https://learnopencv.com/shape-matching-using-hu-moments-c-python/).

Answer (score 0):

Сделал, тестовые файлы распознались. Поделюсь: может, кому-то будет полезно.

Принял три допущения:

1. (условие задачи) Фигуры могут быть только трех видов: квадрат, круг и треугольник
2. (следствие из условия задачи) в фигурах не может быть "вмятин" (не знаю, как красивее сказать, но, надеюсь, понятно)
3. Фигура должна занимать заметное место в изображении. Ну хотя бы процентов 40.

Разбиваю высоту на 30 (эмпирически подобрал) равных частей.  И каждую такую горизониальную линию прохожу от начала до конца с шагом ширина/30. И если предыдущая точка была белой, а текущая черной - запоминаю эту точку как точку контура, фиксируя также направление (ч-б или б-ч).

Затем самое трудное - сортирую эти точки, чтоб точки контура шли по порядку в контуре.

Затем ищу стороны - то есть точки подряд, почти лежащие на прямой (определяю по углу наклона, допустимое отклонение 0.3). И считаю стороны.
3 - треугольник, 4 - квадрат, остальное - круг.

Если кому-то интересно - могу кинуть ссылку на GitHub с кодом (Laravel 9)